# Why Ajax call is automatically executing error and complete blocks before posting the data to the server

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have the following the code which serialises the form data before sending it to the server. However due to some reasons, this code is first executing error and complete block before making the ajax call and never executes success block although server returns plain text.

```
$("#btnUpload").click(function () {
    debugger;
    UploadControl.Upload();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: $("#hdnUploadPOFile").val(),
        data: $('#uploadControlForm').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            debugger;
            // ProcessFileMessage(response);
            toastr.success('File processed successfully');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert('hi');
        }
    })
});
```

And the following is the code written for controller's action

```
[HttpPost]
        public ContentResult UploadControlUpload(PrintempsFileUploadViewModel model)
        {
            string[] errors;
            UploadedFile[] files = UploadControlExtension.GetUploadedFiles("UploadControl", UploadControlHelper.Settings, out errors, (s, e) => { }, UploadControl_FilesUploadComplete);
            PrintempsFileUploadViewModel printempsFileUploadViewModel = Session["PrintempsFileUploadViewModel"] as PrintempsFileUploadViewModel;
            string fileProcessingMessage = "Exceptions found"; // PrintempsFileHomeService.ProcessPrintempsPurchaseOrderData(model.Season, FileName);
            return Content(fileProcessingMessage);
        }
```

could some one help me find out the issue with my ajax code ?

Comment: error callback can get parameters... try using them to see the error and to get better help

Comment: Why you require this Text Datatype insted of 'Json' : dataType: 'text',  and url: $("#hdnUploadPOFile").val(), is your URL

Comment: $("#hdnUploadPOFile").val() is my URL. I have tried changing the data type to JSON, but it did not help at all.

Comment: @user1737473 I will shorten my answer below, when I find the exact changes you need to fix your issue, after you comment on sending form.serialize() to server.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if this minimal amount of code to send the form data helps:

View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index800</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btn").click(function (ev) {

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/Index800",
                    data: { message: $("form").serialize() },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#output").val(JSON.stringify(response.AjaxDataSend));


                    },
                    error: function (Result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });

            })


        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            @*need name attrib to serialize before ajaxing to server*@
            <input type="text" value="one" id="one" name="one" />
            <input type="text" value="two" id="two" name="two" />
            <input type="text" value="three" id="three" name="three" />
            <input type="text" value="four" id="four" name="four" />

            <input type="text" value="APDH" id="ddOrganization" />
            <input type="text" id="output" style="width:600px" />

            <input type="button" value="Ok" id="btn" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller/Model  I am returning proprietary data to show how to return data:

```
public class AjaxDataSend
{
    public string from { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost] //message needs to have same name as in .ajax
    public ActionResult Index800(string message)
    {
        AjaxDataSend ads = new AjaxDataSend
        {
            from = "2017-05-03",
            to = "2017-05-05"
        };
        AjaxDataSend ads2 = new AjaxDataSend
        {
            from = "2017-05-10",
            to = "2017-05-12"
        };

        IList<AjaxDataSend> list = new List<AjaxDataSend>();
        list.Add(ads);
        list.Add(ads2);

        return Json(new
        {
            AjaxDataSend = list
        }
                , @"application/json");
    }
```